# how to return a var in swift

Tags: ios, function, swift

I'm so confused because I'm habituated to get a var by function like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var timerVal:Int = calcolo()

    func calcolo() -> Int {

        return 0;
           }

}
```

But it don't work. The problem is: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call.

Comment: look up getter syntax again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- when invoking an instance method to initialize a property, you have to explicitly specify the instance, i.e. `self`
- an instance property cannot be initialized with a statement or expression directly or indirectly referencing `self`, because `self` is unavailable until all properties have been initialized

To fix the problem you can declare the property as `lazy` - it will be initialized the first time it is accessed, so after the instance initialization:

```
lazy var timerVal:Int = self.calcolo()
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `timerVal` is an instance property and `calcolo` is an instance method. You cannot call an instance method directly in the default value of an instance property, because at the time the default value is being assigned to the instance method, there is no instance! The instance is exactly what you are in the middle of creating.

If you meant to write a calculated property, the syntax looks like this:

```
var timerVal:Int {
    return 0
}
```

If you meant to write a property whose default value is calculated, the syntax looks like this:

```
var timerVal:Int = {
    return 0
}()
```

Or you could declare the instance property `lazy`, so that by the time it is initialized, the instance *does* exist.

Or you could move the declaration of `calcolo` up to the top level of your file, where it is no longer an instance method but is a global method. Now you can call it in your initializer.

Comment: Hey @matt, (+1 to this answer btw) but do you mind clarifying a little bit more about the difference between those two bits of code? "calculated property" vs "default value is calculated"?

Comment: From my own testing, I guess the difference is that the first bit of code means the `timerVal` is not reassignable? Whereas it's reassignable in the second since the 0 is just a "default" value?

Comment: That's pretty much right. The first example is a calculated property (read Apple's docs on this). A calculated property has no storage; it is calculated. You can assign into it, syntactically, if you write a getter for it. But you are still not storing the value in it (though your setter can store elsewhere). The second example is a normal stored variable, and we are merely assigning its initial, default value by means of a calculation.

Comment: @matt you're wrong, you can access an instance method (I didn't know either until now). Check Antonio's answer.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Matt's not wrong. He mentioned that "you could declare the instance property lazy" in his answer. He just didn't write out the code.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert No, what I said is right. I have correctly explained why the OP's code didn't work. That was the question. The question was not "what _else_ could you do so that _does_ work?" I gave some possible alternatives, but that was purely icing on the cake. I'm not even sure what the OP was trying to do! It seems kind of silly to me.

Comment: @matt my guess he's trying to avoid cluttering the init method. It's very common practice in modern dynamic languages to init ivars as part of the definition and often you won't have an init method at all. That wasn't possible in  Obj-C but is possible in Swift, and I'm guessing it will become the standard pattern once the community gets comfortable with it.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I don't think we know that. I'm not even sure the OP realizes that he can perform his calculation and create the default value in an init method (although he can't _call_ an instance method in an init method).